# How to add the original data to a contour plot without external libraries in R?

Tags: r

I have a standard unfilled contour plot in R. It has two regions and was generated using the KDE function. It looks to be normalised to between 0 and 1. I want to plot the original data over it however R just seems to plot the data on a separate graph each time. I have tried using lines() and points(). So my two questions are: 1) how do you un-normalise a contour plot (did KDE normalise the output?) and 2) how do you plot the original data over a contour plot?

Skeleton code:

```
data.kde <- kde(data)
plot(data)
contour(data.kde$estimate, add=TRUE)
```

I am not sure if the add=TRUE statement is working, as the data is on different scales as my contour plot has come out normalised to between 0 and 1. If I normalise my original data it does not quite match where it should on the contour - the two data centres are slightly off from the contour centres.

Comment: Which KDE function? There is no KDE function in base R. There are at least two external packages with functions called `kde`, and I think the most commonly used KDE function is `kde2d` from `MASS`.

Comment: @AllanCameron Sorry forgot it wasn't part of base R. It is the ks package - the function is just kde(). I will add more information to my question now with some skeleton code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your data is like this:

```r
library(ks)

set.seed(1)
x    <- rnorm(100)
y    <- rnorm(100)
data <- cbind(x, y)
```

Then you can do:

```
KDE <- kde(data)

plot(KDE, drawpoints = TRUE)
```

[image]

Or if you want to use `contour`

```r
contour(x = KDE$eval.points[[1]], y = KDE$eval.points[[2]], z = KDE$estimate)
points(KDE$x[,1], KDE$x[,2])
```

[image]
<sup>Created on 2022-02-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I was looking for! I couldn't find an explanation online that didn't just say to use ggplot. When you type plot(KDE), what exactly is being plotted by default? As KDE has multiple objects within it such as x and estimate? I assume points(KDE$x[,1], KDE$x[,2]) is adding points from object x and the indexing is specifying the columns?

Comment: Ultimately, `plot(KDE)` calls `plot.kde(KDE)` which calls `plot.kde.2d`, which actually calls `contour`. I've just noticed `plot.kde` has a `drawpoints` argument, which makes the whole thing very easy. The plotting functions were written by the ks authors to take the data structure and use its components to do what I did manually with the components in my second example.